# ramp up step count and ramp up time in concurrency thread group

Tags: performance, testing, load

How to configure ramp up step count and ramp up time in concurrency thread group?
I have tried 500 threads needs to configure in concurrency thread group with ramup 10min and ramp steps count :500 Hold rate :10min.Every time while exceution I am seeing the errors. What can be the configuration for 500 threads.